# How to concatenate two mutable array in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to concatenate two mutable array

In first array I am getting value like this

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7f9102d7a100>(
12/05/2017,
17/05/2017,
17/05/2017,
17/05/2017,
17/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
22/05/2017,
23/05/2017,
23/05/2017
)
```

In Second array

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7f9102d7a360>(
17:12,
14:11,
14:25,
17:07,
18:11,
10:04,
10:05,
10:07,
10:53,
13:05,
16:01,
16:31,
16:38,
17:40,
17:44,
17:47,
09:38,
11:25
)
```

I need to show array like this

```
12/05/2017 17:12
```

How can I do this?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as below.

```
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0;i<firstArray.count;i++) {
    [finalArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [firstArray objectAtIndex:i], [secondArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

Comment: @FahimParker perfect solution and easy to use.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This way with count check

```
    NSArray *arr1 = @[@"12/05/2017",
                     @"17/05/2017"];
    NSArray *arr2 = @[@"17:12",
                      @"14:11"];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSAssert(arr1.count == arr2.count, @"arrays count not equal");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.count; i++) {
        [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", arr1[i], arr2[i]]];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this also

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [@[@"111",@"222"] mutableCopy]; // sample array
NSMutableArray *array2 = [@[@"333",@"444"] mutableCopy]; // sample array
NSMutableArray *array3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
[array3 addObjectsFromArray:array2];
```